# Perl Mojolicious, Mojo::UserAgent use IPv4

Tags: perl, ipv4, mojolicious, mojo-useragent

How can I tell my Mojolicious `Mojo::UserAgent` to use only IPv4, is that possible somehow?

(something like: `wget --inet4-only https://blabli.com`)

Reason why I need this is that in Openshift Cluster where I use this Agent, IPv6 doesn't work.

Comment: I tried to find a list of all `MOJO_*` variables but it doesn't seem to exist. I thought there may be a `MOJO_NO_IPV4` / `MOJO_NO_IPV6` (there's not) - You may need to ask directly if you receive no feedback here: https://docs.mojolicious.org/#SUPPORT

Comment: Can't you configure your system to simply not use IPv6 globally, if this does not work? Might be better than trying to work around in each application. See [gai.conf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/gai.conf.5.html) regarding the setup for name resolution.

Comment: OP also asked about LWP: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77279177/perl-lwpuseragent-use-ipv4

Comment: Are you running into a problem where Mojo::UserAgent is getting an IPv6 address back when it wants to resolve a name? How are you resolving host names?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich will try it, it will take some time because I don't have root rights on Run Time on that mashine but I will try it.

Comment: @briandfoy
$mojoUrl = Mojo::URL->new($uri);
my $ua   = Mojo::UserAgent->new;
$tx      = $ua->get($mojoUrl);

I posted call log with Code sniped from Rawly Flower
My assumtion that IPv6 is culprit is because of wget behaviour where " --inet4-only" solved the issue

Comment: I'm more interested in how any program resolves a host name when it asks the system to do that. If the system is limited to IPv4, it shouldn't return IPv6 for any program.

Answer (score 8):

You can force the use of ipv4 using the [`IO::Socket::IP`](https://docs.mojolicious.org/IO/Socket/IP) module to add `socket_options` to the user agents socket.

```perl
use Mojo::UserAgent;
use IO::Socket::IP -register;

# PF_INET  -> ipv4
# PF_INET6 -> ipv6
my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new(socket_options => { Domain => PF_INET });

print $ua->get("www.google.com")->result->body; # Uses ipv4
```

Comment: I tried your Code sniped I am getting still same behavior but at least now I can assume that Mojo:UserAgent works over IPv4. Still any clue why I got 120 seconds delay when in  wget "--inet4-only" solved the problem

 wget https://some-service-in-other-openshift-cluster-which-have-some-network-issues.com/some-path
 (DELAY 120 SECONDS)
 wget --inet4-only https://some-service-in-other-openshift-cluster-which-have-some-network-issues.com
 (WORKS OK)

Comment: perl code_sniped_from_rawley_fowler_ipv4.pl    # with MOJO_CLIENT_DEBUG=1
 
`-- Blocking request (https://some-service-in-other-openshift-cluster-which-have-some-network-issues.com/some-path)

-- Connect 2dcd0a5f96d41c9c82c2d03672272bd5 (https://some-service-in-other-openshift-cluster-which-have-some-network-issues.com:443

(DELAY 120 SECONDS)

-- Client >>> Server (https://some-service-in-other-openshift-cluster-which-have-some-network-issues.com/some-path)

GET /some-path HTTP/1.1\x0d

Accept-Encoding: gzip\x0d`

an so on with no any delay more

Comment: If you have other problems, please make a new question.

Comment: Just info if somebody read this in the future. I solved my problem with mandatory IPv4 by changing "precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  10" to "precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  100" in https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/gai.conf.5.html so now my all calls(not only perl) on OS level goes over IPv4. Big thanks to @Steffen Ullrich for a tip. Issue is resolved.